# Gmail softbounced forwarded messages with DMARC

Tags: email, dkim, spf

-2

I have a system with spam/virus scanner (EFA) in front of a mailserver. On the mailserver mails coming from a sender with DMARC and forwarded to external emails like Gmail do Softbounce. I installed postsrsd on the mailserver and removed all body rewriting from the spamserver (running MailScanner/Spamassassin). I am struggling with this for 4 days now, and just can't make it work. Mostly also because I don't know why the mails are bounced or how to check this. I sent a test mail(without dmarc) to an emailaddress which is forwarded to my gmail account and in the header there is this line: spf=pass (google.com: domain of srs0=baj9=ql=domain.nl=info@mail.domain.net designates 83.96.x.x as permitted sender) Which seems to me that SRS is working. However all mail from DMARC senders is bounced. Does anybody have a tip or suggestion on what is wrong or how to troubleshoot this problem? Thanks, Roger

Comment: Do you have any messages (perhaps from Junk Mail in Gmail) that are being filtered because of this (soft bounce)? Or are all the emails in question actually being rejected? If we could see the headers from an effected message, it'd be helpful.  Also, we'd need to know the DMARC & SPF records for the original sending domain AND your domain (that is doing forwarding) so we can look at the interactions. (note: auto-forwards to external systems are generally a bad idea since they, by design, can easily fail these types of checks [to prevent compromised accounts from being turned into spam relays])

Comment: Yes, but I am unable to post them here, because they are too long.

Comment: Feel free to use a PasteBin (or similar).  Or, if all else fails, to add a screen shot of the headers to the question.  (for that matter, I'm quite certain that Qs don't have length limits -- just make sure to set it as a pre-formatted block)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bmYGN1pZ
Thanks so far,
Roger

Comment: Well the mail is coming from the outside so `st***er.com` is not a domain of mine. Gmail softbounced this mail and for that it stays in my mailqueue. The `ne***rt.net` servers are my servers which indeed giving this problem. But indeed, I also saw the line that the ip address is authenticated for SPF, however that is not one of mine IP addresses.

Comment: I send an email to be forwarded to my gmail account (From a domain without DMARC) it is deliverd and the header in the gmail account has: `spf=pass (google.com: domain of srs0=szj4=qn=chin.nl=klantense@mail.nedport.net designates 83.96.158.143 as permitted sender)` . That is the IP address of my mailserver which forwards and uses SRS, so it seems to work.

Comment: From the postfix log: `Feb  6 20:26:06 mail postfix/smtp[1362]: 318CA3A: to=<stef@gmail.com>, orig_to=<stefan@online.com>, relay=alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.217.194.27]:25, delay=8790, delays=8786/0/3/1.6, dsn=4.7.1, status=SOFTBOUNCE (host alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.217.194.27] said: 550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from ing.nl is not accepted due to domain's 550-5.7.1 DMARC policy. Please contact the administrator of ing.nl domain if 550-5.7.1 this was a legitimate mail. Please visit 550-5.7.1` And some link

Comment: The email from an account without DMARC doesn't say anything about DMARC, it just shows that the message passed a SPF check (that specific one says that Google agrees that `mail.nedport.net` is allowed to send from that IP)  So that doesn't really affect the DMARC portion (which makes sense, there is no DMARC to check)

Comment: The postfix log is telling.  It explicitly calls out that the ing.nl folks have setup a DMARC policy which is causing relayed messages to be rejected.  (Makes sense, ING, as a financial firm, would put strong authenticity controls in place to help cut down on email spoofing).  You probably aren't going to get much further with this configuration.  ING doesn't want anyone to even get close to looking like "ING Official" unless they really are; but that is exactly what auto-forwarding does.  So their policy stops it.  Remember when I said it is "generally a bad idea", this is why.

Comment: auto-forwarding should normally not alter the DKIM, but it does for some reason. I just can't figure out why. I am also looking at rewriting the sender, but haven't searched for that yet.
Thanks,Roger

Answer (score 0):

OK, if I'm reading this correctly, the mail is going from `@st***er.com` to gmail (and the DMARC passes: line 27).  Then Gmail has been configured to auto-forward to a `@ne***rt.net` address (and again, this looks to pass DMARC: lines 9-13).

Everything in this setup shows that it *should* be working.  And, since you received an email so that you could look at the headers, I'm further assuming that's true (the message was delivered).

I did a quick check of the DMARC record at `_dmarc.st***er.com` and see that you have *strict* alignment enabled ("...`adkim=s; aspf=s`...").  While it shouldn't matter (again, the gmail test you posted the headers for show that everything worked; at least as far as SPF/DKIM/DMARC go) there is a possibility that adhering to the strict alignment is causing trouble on the ne***rt.net mail servers.  That would indicate that ne***rt.net is probably where the issue occurs; but you may be able to avoid that entirely by using relaxed alignment (either change those `=s` to `=r`, or just leave out the `aspf` and `adkim` terms altogether).

If you have the issue with a forwarding address that uses DMARC Forensic Reporting (their _dmarc DNS record will contain a `ruf=mailto:` term) then you could try contacting the mail admins for that system and see if they'll send you a copy of the forensic report for the failure.  Coin-flip, many places won't bother, but if you can get someone to send you a copy of the Forensic Report on a failure, then you'll see exactly why their server denied the message.

This was a little much for a comment (and if it works, it is the answer).  But please do let me know if this isn't it so I can modify this answer to let folks know it didn't work.

`NOTE :: for anyone asking for email help):: While I did try to still obscure the messaging domains, since @Ben went through the effort to dummy them in the headers, this isn't useful for privacy or diagnostics.  As you can see, I had to work to figure out what the actual domains were (IPs are still listed, so it was do-able) so that I could lookup the SPF and DMARC records for the domains involved.  So obscuring isn't helpful for diagnostics.  And, email is a public transit system -- as in, everything is designed to work & maintain security in a "white box" fashion where the public is knowledgeable about the interactions.  Obscuring public hostnames & IPs in a email header doesn't actually give you any extra security.  (Do feel free to redact internal-only hostnames & IPs from within your system, that is a valid approach.)  Nothing against Ben here, just noting for anyone seeing this in the future that obscuring already public information doesn't really do anything except slow down the person working to research the issue.`